# Toast shows multiple times on value change of string

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

```
 val phoneNumber = remember { "" }

Toast.makeText(context,"Otp sent to : " + phoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

I used this toast in success result but it shows again when i changed phonenumber.

Answer (score 0):

If your toast is in the composition layer, as soon as you change the phoneNumber, your composable will recompose, and your toast method will be called.
If you want to show it only once on success, you can call it in a `LaunchedEffect` with appropriate keys (if required).

Example:

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(key1 = response) {
  Toast.makeText(context,"Otp sent to : " + phoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Here, the code inside LaunchedEffect will only be called whenever the `response` changes. You can now add a condition to show it only if response is success, for example.